# Como esconder o cookies.txt do curl

Tags: php, javascript, html, libcurl, cookies

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho um código em php que faz uma requisição com curl em uma pagina, porém ele salva os cookies em um arquivo de texto cookies.txt, e qualquer um pode ter acesso a esse arquivo em um link direto "**www.meusite.com.br/cookies.txt**" desejo saber como oculto isso, pois a segurança de minha aplicação ficara em risco caso alguém encontre este arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já há uma série de postagens no site sobre como bloquear um cliente externo de acessar um arquivo.

Por exemplo, se for um servidor Apache:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=.htaccess+bloquear

Melhor que isso seria mudar o caminho onde o arquivo é salvo, pondo fora da raiz da sua hospedagem (por exemplo, fora do diretório `httpdocs` ou equivalente):

```
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, caminho );
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, caminho );
```

- `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` é o caminho onde os *cookies* são armazenados e lidos durante o uso normal.
- `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` é o caminho onde os *cookies* são armazenados depois de chamada a função de *cleanup* .

Veja as opções do cURL para PHP no manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Obrigado mais me parece que mesmo assim com um scanner é possivel encontrar esse arquivo de cookies em meu site

Comment: Mas estou passando isso para você poder por os arquivos FORA do site. Editei o post para deixar mais claro. Se o que quer é apenas bloquear os arquivos, já ha respostas no site. Se for apache, basta pesquisar por .htaccess

Comment: Obrigado irei me informar mais sobre :)